# Getting undefined for fnGetData() in DataTables

Tags: datatables

What I want is to get row data when users click on the table's tbody but I keep getting `undefined` for these `datatables` functions.

Data comes from a `node-mysql` module. And for testing purposes, after the `table` is initialized and data's propertly arrived I've set:

```
"fnDrawCallback" : function() {
        console.log('this:' + this);
        console.log('oTable.fnGetData():' + oTable.fnGetData());
        console.log('JSON.stringify(oTable.fnGetData():' + JSON.stringify(oTable.fnGetData()));
        console.log('JSON.stringify(oTable.fnGetData():' + JSON.stringify(oTable.fnGetData()[0]));
        console.log('oTable.fnGetData()[0]:' + oTable.fnGetData()[0]);
},
```

The result is this:

```
this:[object Object] tables_offline.js:40
oTable.fnGetData():[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] tables_offline.js:41
JSON.stringify(oTable.fnGetData():[{"id":1,"age":"23","vol":26227,"tlg":4.93,"r":18.15},{"id":2,"age":"13","vol":6378,"tlg":3.97,"r":16.76},{"id":3,"age":"54","vol":131626,"tlg":6.49,"r":11.1}] tables_offline.js:42
JSON.stringify(oTable.fnGetData()[0]:{"id":1,"age":"23","vol":26227,"tlg":4.93,"r":18.15} tables_offline.js:43
oTable.fnGetData()[0]:[object Object]
```

It's not an array... Maybe this is the weird thing.

---

I've tried `debugging` with `chrome`, setting

```
$('#myTable').on('click', 'tr', function(){ 
    var oTable = $('#myTable').DataTable();
    debugger;
});
```

And here's a [screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/puyw7izzz/) of what's coming from the variable `oTable`. I'm not sure but shouldn't I be able to see the `functions` right there? I can't query something like `oTable.fnGetData()` 'cause it's `undefined`.
Let me know if you need something else from my side in order for you to help me.

**EDIT**

What I want basicaly is to get `row data` when users click on the table's `tbody`. I can't get there since `oTable = $('#myTable').DataTable(); oTable.fnGetData()'` throws undefined.

I'll try to clarify a bit more.

`tables_offline.js` is the file that loads the `datatable`, there I define my `oTable` variable. While searching for help I came across this [post](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/145) (I'm using `mData` for the columns definition) and I'm not sure if this is the case but it may help.
I make use of `fnDrawCallback` just for testing `oTable` in the console, it's not part of the original code.

```
var oTable = $("#myTable").dataTable({                                           
        'fnServerParams': function (aoData) {
            aoData.push({ "name": "startDate", "value": startDate });
            aoData.push({ "name": "endDate", "value": endDate });
        },
        'sAjaxSource':  '/url',
        'sAjaxDataProp': '',
        'bProcessing': true,                        
        'sDom':'t',       
        "aoColumns": [                              
                { "bVisible": false, "mDataProp": "pcrc_id"},
                { "sWidth": "25%","sTitle": "age", "mDataProp": "pcrc"},
                { "sWidth": "25%","sTitle": "Vol", "mDataProp": "volumen"},
                { "sWidth": "25%","sTitle": "tlg", "mDataProp": "tlg"},
                { "sWidth": "25%","sTitle": "r", "mDataProp": "reitero",
                        "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {                                               
                                    return data + '%';
                            } 
                    }
        ],              
        "oLanguage": {
                "sUrl": "/javascripts/i18n/dataTables.Spanish.json"
        },                 
        "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        "bSort": false,
        "bInfo" : false,                                
        "bPaginate": false,
        "fnDrawCallback" : function() {
        console.log('this:' + this);
        console.log('oTable.fnGetData():' + oTable.fnGetData());
        console.log('JSON.stringify(oTable.fnGetData():' + JSON.stringify(oTable.fnGetData()));
        console.log('JSON.stringify(oTable.fnGetData()[0]:' + JSON.stringify(oTable.fnGetData()[0]));
        console.log('oTable.fnGetData()[0]:' + oTable.fnGetData()[0]);
    },
        "bFilter": false
});
```

**EDIT 2**

New [screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/aok0x3xfx/) after accesing `oTable` when a row's clicked. If I dig deep into `context` I see the data but it's the full thing, not just the row clicked. I'd like to use a function to get clicked row data.

Comment: I think it'd be great if you made a JSFiddle out of all of this. I will say that because you set your variable as `var oTable` within the function, I believe you limited the scope of that variable to be local to only that function. Try taking out `var` to see if you get access.

Comment: Sorry to say, this question is very confusing :) How and then exactly do you call `fnDrawCallback`? What is `tables_offline.js`?

Comment: @Zhouster tried removing `var` and it's the same. I'll try to set a fiddle!

Comment: @davidkonrad I've added some more data in the question.

Comment: I think you're focussing on fnDrawCallback too much - it would be more helpful to see your initialisation code (ie where the ... is in your example)

Comment: @markpsmith done. `fnDrawCallback` isn't a part of the code, it's just used for checking the `oTable` var.

Comment: ok, so is the data showing properly or not?

Comment: @markpsmith `console.log(JSON.stringify(oTable.fnGetData()))` shows the data (inside `fnDrawCallback`). Once table is initialized I can't use `fnDrawCallback` at all, `undefined` every time.

Comment: So is the information that the fnDrawCallback printing out correct? It looks like it exists at that point (though it does seem a bit weird to call a variable in its own initialization). Also, why not just `console.log` the entire object, as opposed to stringify?

Comment: @Zhouster yes, the information is OK. And yes, it's weird but it was just for testing purposes. When I'd really like to use `fnGetData()` is on `tr` click, and there it's all about `undefined`. So, doing a `console.log(oTable)` after the row's clicked, shows a new object. I've added a new screenshot in the question.

Comment: Okay, gotcha. I think it'd still be great if you made a JSFiddle. It's hard to help you debug without working with what you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the fnDrawCallback stuff, I think it's distracting you from the actual problem.

Try this:

```
var oTable = $("#myTable").dataTable({                                           
        'fnServerParams': function (aoData) {
            aoData.push({ "name": "startDate", "value": startDate });
            aoData.push({ "name": "endDate", "value": endDate });
        },
        'sAjaxSource':  '/url',
        'sAjaxDataProp': '',
        'bProcessing': true,                        
        'sDom':'t',       
        "aoColumns": [                              
                { "bVisible": false, "mDataProp": "pcrc_id"},
                { "sWidth": "25%","sTitle": "age", "mDataProp": "pcrc"},
                { "sWidth": "25%","sTitle": "Vol", "mDataProp": "volumen"},
                { "sWidth": "25%","sTitle": "tlg", "mDataProp": "tlg"},
                { "sWidth": "25%","sTitle": "r", "mDataProp": "reitero",
                        "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {                                               
                                    return data + '%';
                            } 
                    }
        ],              
        "oLanguage": {
                "sUrl": "/javascripts/i18n/dataTables.Spanish.json"
        },                 
        "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        "bSort": false,
        "bInfo" : false,                                
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bFilter": false
});

oTable.$('tr').click( function () {
    var data = oTable.fnGetData( this );
    console.log(data);
  } );
```

Note that the oTable var is still in scope so you don't need to use `var oTable = $('#myTable').DataTable()`.

This example is copied verbatim from the [Datatables API documentation](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnGetData)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. `click` function doesn't get fired when a row's clicked. And I can't find why, I bypassed everything and fired the whole code on document ready.

Comment: possibly because oTable is out of scope?

Comment: I did a `copy-paste` of your code. I `debugged` between definition and  `tr click`. And the table is just `thead` and `tbody`, no data so no `tr` just yet. When I let the code run, data populates but after that, oTable's out of scope as you say. I'm not getting this.

Comment: so is your table not populated when the page loads?

Comment: user submits dates into a datepicker, then there's the call to populate the table. But still, for testing I've called that function on pageload with some random dates, and still, I can't make it work.